# location picker for .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I'm developing an app to control onsite projects. I need to let the user specify the project's location from its country down to its address, and latitude/longitude coordinates.

The problem is, location information isn't uniformly described across countries, i.e., countries have different names in their location hierarchy. So if one project is located in the USA, it will have a hierarchy of:

```
Country / State / City
```

Chile, on the other hand, has a hierarchy of:

```
Country / Region / County / City / district / neighborhood
```

How should I model this?

Is there a premade `.net` module I can stick into my project that would work? Should I just simplify the hierarchy into four distinct levels, and let the user deal with the complexity of different hierarchies across countries?

The best solution for me would be to use a premade assembly that I could stick into my code with little effort, but I'm not afraid to code an implementation on my own.

The problem is that every solution I manage to cook seems too complicated to be practical, so any advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just store the latitude/longitude coordinates and then use GMaps to look up the location:

```
static string baseUri = 
  "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false";
string location = string.Empty;

public static void RetrieveFormatedAddress(string lat, string lng)
{
    string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat, lng);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string result = wc.DownloadString(requestUri);
        var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(result);
        var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants() where 
            elm.Name == "status" select elm).FirstOrDefault();
        if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
        {
            var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants() where 
                elm.Name == "formatted_address" select elm).FirstOrDefault();
            requestUri = res.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here's a simple version of the reverse:

```
public static Coordinate GetCoordinates(string region)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {

        string uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='" + region + 
          "'&output=csv&key=sadfwet56346tyeryhretu6434tertertreyeryeryE1";

        string[] geocodeInfo = client.DownloadString(uri).Split(',');

        return new Coordinate(Convert.ToDouble(geocodeInfo[2]), 
                   Convert.ToDouble(geocodeInfo[3]));
    }
}

public struct Coordinate
{
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public Coordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        lat = latitude;
        lng = longitude;

    }

    public double Latitude { get { return lat; } set { lat = value; } }
    public double Longitude { get { return lng; } set { lng = value; } }

}
```

Comment: this could work, the problem is latitude and longitude won't always be readily available, and making the user manually get these values could prove to be impractical. perhaps the inverse also exists? so if the user has lon an lat he could input them, and if not maybe click on a google map and have the api return all relevant info?

Comment: great! thanks for this, I'll be checking it out as soon as I finish refactoring